# Queries in open office database

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am using open office database 3.3 as my database. I was able to establish the connection successfully but getting an error while trying to execute the queries:

```
 public class openofficeupdate {
String databaseurl="C:\\Users\\RAVITEJA\\Documents\\BluetoothExchangeFolder\\salesforce.odb";
openofficeupdate() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    System.out.println("Entered into constructor");
    Connection connection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
   try{
    Class c=openofficeclass();
    System.out.println("Class name set");

    Connection cntn=createConnection(databaseurl);
    connection=cntn;
    System.out.println("connection created");

    Statement stmt=createStatement(cntn);
    statement=stmt;
    System.out.println("Statement created");

    executeQueries(stmt);
    System.out.println("Query executed");

    closeStatement(stmt);
    System.out.println("Statement closed");

    closeConnection(cntn);
    System.out.println("Connection closed");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

        closeStatement(statement);
        System.out.println("Statement closed");

        closeConnection(connection);
        System.out.println("Connection closed");
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    new openofficeupdate();
}

private Class openofficeclass() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
}

private Connection createConnection(String databaseurl) throws SQLException{
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" +databaseurl);
}

private Statement createStatement(Connection cntn) throws SQLException{
    return cntn.createStatement();
}

private void closeStatement(Statement stmt) throws SQLException{
    stmt.close();
}

private void closeConnection(Connection cntn) throws SQLException{
    cntn.close();
}

private void executeQueries(Statement stmt) throws SQLException{

    System.out.println("Going to execute query");
    //int status=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Mobiles(Mobile ID,Employee ID,Start_Track_Time,Stop_Track_Time) values(987654321,198,09:30:00,10:30:00)");
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from Mobiles;");
    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("Inside row "+rs.getRowId(1));
    }
    System.out.println("Query executed with status ");
}
}
```

I set the **hsqldb.jar** as my class path.  The output for the above code showing is...

```
Entered into constructor
Class name set
connection created
Statement created
Going to execute query
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MOBILES
Statement closed
Connection closed
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

When you're connecting to the database, you're doing so as a user who doesn't have privileges to access some entity in the database. You need to set the user for your connection to a user that has the appropriate privileges. According to this the username you want is SA

> It may surprise the database developer to learn that OpenOffice.org Base already has a user account. This user account (named SA)...

Use the [setClientInfo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo%28java.util.Properties%29) method on the Connection Object to set the username to "SA".

Comment: Thank you @Kurtis Nusbaum but how can i set appropriate privileges to a user in open office database.

Comment: What package are you getting the Connection class from? That will help me determine how to answer you better.

Comment: I am using java.sql.*; for sql connections and queries

Comment: I found some where that by default open office database is readonly.. and we should create a user manually with sql . I tried this but the query is not executing......... create user sfts password trackingsystem admin

Comment: Can you post a link to the OO documentation that you're reading?

Comment: sure... This is the link i found   http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/how-to-create-an-openofficeorg-database-log-on-a127064